# Uncaught TypeError: $notify when creating global notification in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

i was following the step here.https://vuejsfeed.com/blog/notification-library-for-vue-js which was working fine.
i wanted to make it a global function and this is what i did.

The component part is this one

```
<template>
<notifications group="app" position="bottom center" width="400"/>    
<button @click="testing">notify</button>

</template>
<script>
import { notificate } from '../../general-functions/notification';

export default {
methods: {

    testing () {
      notificate('msg-title','<p><b>How about No?</b></p>','error')
    }
}
}
</script>
```

my notificate function is like this.

```
export function notificate (title,text,type){

this.$notify({
        group: 'app',
        title: title,
        text: text,
        type: type,
        speed: 3000
      })
    }
```

On button click the error is following

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$notify' of undefined
```

Comment: The scope of `this` in your `external function` is not what you think it is. You should make this a [mixin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) if you want this to work correctly.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks . that was it.